# Parse.com login with facebook (strange crash) on Android

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using parse.com, and I am trying to make a login with facebook.
Every thing runs smoothly until the point the login process finishes and a callback suppose to be called. What happens is that (after the FB login process finishes) the app crashes, no massage shown on crash, neither logcat showing any information. I am totally lost.

Here is my code:

```
fbloginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
         {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view)
            {
                 //ProgressDialog progress  = ProgressDialog.show(thisActivity, "Please wait", "Loading please wait..", true);
                 //login.fbLogin(thisActivity);
                 ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList("email"), thisActivity, new LogInCallback() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) 
                        {
                            if (user == null) 
                            {
                                Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Facebook login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                //progress.dismiss();
                                toast.show();
                            } 
                            else if (user.isNew()) 
                            {
                                Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                                Intent mainPage = new Intent(thisActivity, MainPage.class);
                                DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);
                                db.open();
                                db.setLoginStatus(DBAdapter.LOGEDIN);
                                db.close();
                                //progress.dismiss();
                                thisActivity.startActivity(mainPage);

                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                                Intent mainPage = new Intent(thisActivity, MainPage.class);
                                DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);
                                db.open();
                                db.setLoginStatus(DBAdapter.LOGEDIN);
                                db.close();
                                //progress.dismiss();
                                thisActivity.startActivity(mainPage);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
         });
```

don't know if this is important but here is the `onActivityResult` code:

```
 @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
         ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
```

I am using facbook 3.0 sdk and parse 1.3 sdk versions.

**EDIT**
**EDIT:**
I think I found the source of the problem, when I am trying to access the declaration of `logIn` of `ParseFacebookUtils` I am getting this page: Class File editor (`the jar of this class file belongs to container 'android dependencies' which does not allow modification to source attachments on its entries.`).
Also I have updated my parse sdk version from 1.2.4 to 1.3 by deleting the old sdk from libs and adding the new one with it's content (total of 4 files and folder).

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know if the app has crashed if no messages are displayed?

Comment: the app just closes, not giving any error (fades away).

Comment: @Vlad Ioffe May I ask what was the concrete solution for reference. What did you exactly do to the manifest?

Comment: @Ivancho I don't remember, I think it was something with `android:noHistory="true"`. I think I removed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason of crash is placed in the second and the last else clause. You are trying to perform some database operation on UI Thread, which is illicited and throws exception on Android >= 4.0. This type of operation should be done on different threads what can be accomplished by using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).

Comment: Maybe it is a problem, but while debugging the program never gets to the firs `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Vlad. 
your onActivityResult must be:

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

cause `Session.getActiveSesion()` returns null, cause parse manage Session themselves.

And don't forget add FACEBOOK_APP_ID in initalize Parse:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, Constants.APPLICATION_ID, Constants.CLIENT_KEY);
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(Constants.FACEBOOK_APP_ID);

    }

}
```